# Why is the childNodes giving me text before input element when I console.log the parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, nodelist

Why when I console.log the parent's childNodes it gives me this 'text' as one of their childNode?

How can I overcome it?

```
 <div id="inputDiv">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the name">
        <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter the age" >
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="text" id="language" placeholder="Enter the language" >
        <input type="text" id="empid" placeholder="Enter a employeeId" disabled>
        <input type="text" id="salary" placeholder="Enter the salary" >
        <input type="text" id="experience" placeholder="Enter experience" >
        <select id="employeesType" onchange="ChangeEmployeeType()">
            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="staff">Staff</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="managerName" placeholder="Enter the manager name">
        <button id="addPerson" onclick="addPerson()">Person</button>
    </div>
```

When I `console.log(getElementById("inputDiv").childNodes);` it produces:

 
Actual Result :

> NodeList(23) [text, input#name, text, input#age, text, input, text, input, text, input#language, text, input#empid, text, input#salary, text, input#experience, text, select#employeesType, text, input#managerName, text, button#addPerson, text]

- 0:text
- 1:input#name
- 2:text
- 3:input#age
- 4:text
- 5:input
- 6:text
- 7:input
- 8:text
- 9:input#language
- 10:text
- 11:input#empid
- 12:text
- 13:input#salary
- 14:text
- 15:input#experience
- 16:text
- 17:select#employeesType
- 18:text
- 19:input#managerName
- 20:text
- 21:button#addPerson
- 22:text
- length:23
- **proto**
- : NodeList

Expected Result :

> NodeList(23) [text, input#name, text, input#age, text, input, text, input, text, input#language, text, input#empid, text, input#salary, text, input#experience, text, select#employeesType, text, input#managerName, text, button#addPerson, text]

- 0:input#name
- 1:input#age
- 2:input
- 3:text
- 4:input
- 5:text
- 6:input#language
- 7:input#empid
- 8:input#salary
- 9:input#experience
- 10:select#employeesType
- 11:input#managerName
- 12:button#addPerson
- length:13
- **proto**
- : NodeList

Comment: New-lines and other white-space characters in the file are also counted as text nodes.

Comment: Log the `.children` instead to include actual elements only.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it worked thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML text elements are actually node elements.

Use `children` if you want only the "real elements" and create an array from them if you need an array of these elements:

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.getElementById("inputDiv").children));
```

```html
<div id="inputDiv">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter the name">
  <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter the age">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="text" id="language" placeholder="Enter the language">
  <input type="text" id="empid" placeholder="Enter a employeeId" disabled>
  <input type="text" id="salary" placeholder="Enter the salary">
  <input type="text" id="experience" placeholder="Enter experience">
  <select id="employeesType" onchange="ChangeEmployeeType()">
    <option value="manager">Manager</option>
    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="managerName" placeholder="Enter the manager name">
  <button id="addPerson" onclick="addPerson()">Person</button>
</div>
```